# Salable quantity in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, quantity, salable

How can i make Quantity and Salable quantity having same value in magento 2.3.3.
https://prnt.sc/xf5mlb
Here it is showing different

Please help

Answer (score 1):

**A fast-forward answer** - you have to create shipments for the orders which were placed for that product.

The  product's actual stock quantity is decreased only when the orders containing that product receive shipments, until then, the *quantity* will not change. The *salable quantity*, however, will decrease as orders are placed and the difference between total quantity from all sources and salable quantity is the amount of *reservations* for that product (basically, the purchased items that were not yet shipped).

**But on the long run**, since projects have their specifics, I think it's important to fully understand the mechanism behind Magento's *Multiple Source Inventory (MSI)*. I recommend reading [the associated documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-learn-more.html) so that you become familiar with the concepts of sources, stocks, salable quantity and reservations.